# Django: Which characters are escaped by render_to_response?

Tags: django, django-templates

Which characters are escaped by Django's render_to_response()?

I have seen:

```
&lt;   <
&gt;   >
&quot; "
&amp;  &
&#39;  '
```

I'm looking for a complete list. (I think the ones above are the only ones that are strictly necessary...?)

Comment: Try looking at `django.shortcuts` source code. Btw, `render_to_response` is not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future, us `render`.

Comment: Thanks! Found it in django/utils/html.py. I have btw switched to using render. In my mind I still think of it as render_to_response after years of writing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the complete list:

```
&lt;   <
&gt;   >
&quot; "
&amp;  &
&#39;  '
```

Found the code in django/utils/html.py

```
def escape(text):
"""
Returns the given text with ampersands, quotes and angle brackets encoded for use in HTML.
"""
return mark_safe(force_text(text).replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&#39;'))
```

Comment: And the relevant docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping